# modal do bootstrap nao funciona

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addhor" role="dialog" >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4>Adicionar Horário</h4>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>teste</p>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

vi esse exemplo como modal no bootstrap, o modal abre mas, nao funciona mostra o conteudo com uma tela meio escura e quando clico em qualquer lugar ele fecha. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

P.S: Descupem os erros de portugues, meu teclado nao tem acentos

Comment: Chamando a modal via JavaScript: `$('#addhor').modal()` funciona sem problemas. Consegue ser mais especifico sobre o problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que o modal funcione deve haver um evento que no caso desse exemplo foi o evento do botão `data-toggle="addhor"`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addhor">
```

Launch demo modal

Pode também mostrar o modal através de javascript

```
$('#addhor').modal('show');
```

Caso nenhum desses exemplos funcione é porque o arquivo javascript do bootstrap não está inserido na pagina.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Para mais detalhes dê uma lida na documentação do [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).